# Center two lined text in table

Tags: html, email, html-table, html-email

I am building an email in HTML and using tables.
I want a two lined text where the top line is bold

```html
  <table style="width:100%"><tr >
    <td style="background-color:#000000;color:#fff;font-family:arial;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-text:center">
      <b>48 HOURS ONLY! </b>
      <br>EXTRA 15% OFF YOUR NEXT ORDER | CODE: B15CX
    </td>
    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

How can I make sure the two lines line up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Edit]**: [Just as Nathan said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67612238/9999313), this answer would not work for most email clients. The cross-client solution should be using `padding-left` as he mentioned:

```html
<table style="width:100%"><tr >
    <td style="background-color:#000000;color:#fff;font-family:arial;padding-left:50px;">
      <b>48 HOURS ONLY! </b>
      <br>
      EXTRA 15% OFF YOUR NEXT ORDER | CODE: B15CX
    </td>
    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

**If your client supports it**, you can use `flex-direction: column`:

```html
<table style="width:100%"><tr >
    <td style="background-color:#000000;color:#fff;font-family:arial;display:flex;justify-content:center;flex-direction:column;align-text:center">
      <b>48 HOURS ONLY! </b>
      <br>
      EXTRA 15% OFF YOUR NEXT ORDER | CODE: B15CX
    </td>
    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: This will not work on Gmail, Outlook, Yahoo or AOL: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-flex-direction/

Answer (score 1):

The use of flexbox is not right--most email clients do not support it: https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex

Just use `padding-left`:

```
<table style="width:100%"><tr >
    <td style="background-color:#000000;color:#fff;font-family:arial;padding-left:50px;">
      <b>48 HOURS ONLY! </b>
      <br>EXTRA 15% OFF YOUR NEXT ORDER | CODE: B15CX
    </td>
    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-direction: column` as https://stackoverflow.com/a/67600433/15963931 said.

If you want to make sure the two lines are line up you can put the text inside a div:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <table style="width:100%"><tr >
    <td style="background-color:#000000;color:#fff;font-family:arial;display:flex;justify-content:center;align-text:center">
      <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
        <b>48 HOURS ONLY! </b>
        <br>EXTRA 15% OFF YOUR NEXT ORDER | CODE: B15CX
          </div>
    </td>
    
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Remove `margin: 0 auto` from `div` if you don't want it aligned to the center.

Comment: Take note this is email and flex support is not good: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-flex-direction/